# How to specify data interval in a R for loop

Tags: r, matlab, for-loop

In Matlab we can specify the interval between data as follows

```
for i = 1:3:n

...

end
```

Given that the for loop structure in R is as follows:

```
for (i in 1:n)
     {

      ...

      }
```

can we specify the data interval in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In R you need to create a sequence first:

```
for (i in seq(1,n,3)) {
...
```